# how to save the field in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to save the field containing like `"holiday"=>["", "monday", "tuesday"]` in to the database?

These can be selected from `drop down{multiple selection}`.

I added the multiple selection with jquery and found difficulty in saving part.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: take `holiday` field as data type "text" and you can directly save array in to it.

Comment: how to use this in edit_page,if saved?can u please explain

Answer (score 1):

Rails works best if you work within the framework and convention.

You can create a model for your `Holiday` by running:

```
rails generate model holiday days:string count:integer
```

This will create a `Holiday` model that inherits from `ApplicationRecord` with the string property `days` and the integer property `count` at the path:

```
app/models/holiday.rb
```

You need to update your database by running the following at the command line:

```
rake db:migrate
```

And now you can create, validate, and save `Holiday`s

```
holiday = Holiday.new
holiday.days = ["", "monday", "tuesday"]
holiday.count = 2
```

Then all you need to do is save it:

```
holiday.save
```